# C: fork() inform parent when child process disconnects

Tags: c, sockets, waitpid

I am doing a simple server/client program in C which listens on a network interface and accepts clients. Each client is handled in a forked process.

The goal I have is to let the parent process know, once a client has disconnected from the child process.

Currently my main loop looks like this:

```
for (;;) {

    /* 1. [network] Wait for new connection... (BLOCKING CALL) */
    fd_listen[client] = accept(fd_listen[server], (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen);

    if (fd_listen[client] < 0) {
        perror("ERROR on accept");
        exit(1);
    }


    /* 2. [process] Call socketpair */
    if ( socketpair(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0, fd_comm) != 0 ) {
        perror("ERROR on socketpair");
        exit(1);
    }


    /* 3. [process] Call fork */
    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("ERROR on fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* 3.1 [process] Inside the Child */
    if (pid == 0) {

        printf("[child] num of clients: %d\n", num_client+1);
        printf("[child] pid: %ld\n", (long) getpid());

        close(fd_comm[parent]);     // Close the parent socket file descriptor
        close(fd_listen[server]);   // Close the server socket file descriptor

        // Tasks that the child process should be doing for the connected client
        child_processing(fd_listen[client]);

        exit(0);
    }
    /* 3.2 [process] Inside the Parent */
    else {

        num_client++;
        close(fd_comm[child]);      // Close the child socket file descriptor
        close(fd_listen[client]);   // Close the client socket file descriptor

        printf("[parent] num of clients: %d\n", num_client);

        while ( (w = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)) > 0) {
            printf("[EXIT] child %d terminated\n", w);
            num_client--;
        }
    }

}/* end of while */
```

It all works well, the only problem I have is (probably) due to the blocking `accept` call.

When I connect to the above server, a new child process is created and `child_processing` is called.

However when I disconnect with that client, the main parent process does not know about it and does NOT output `printf("[EXIT] child %d terminated\n", w);`

But, when I connect with a second client **after** the first client has disconnected, the main loop is able to finally process the `while ( (w = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)) > 0)` part and tell me that the **first client** has disconnected.

If there will be only ever one client connecting and disconnecting afterwards, my main parent process will never be able to tell if it has disconnected or not.

Is there any way to tell the parent process that my client already left?

**UPDATE**

As I am a real beginner with c, it would be nice if you provide some short snippets to your answer so I can actually understand it :-)

Comment: Use threads. The `fork()` model is basically obsolete.

Comment: @EJP, by no means `fork()` is obsolete. See answers below - they actually provide for a solution **unavailable** natively with threads.

Answer (score 0):

Your waitpid usage is not correct. You have a non-blocking call so if the child is not finished then then the call gets 0:

> **waitpid()**: on success, returns the process ID of the child whose state
>   has changed; if `WNOHANG` was specified and one or more child(ren)
>   specified by pid exist, but have not yet changed state, then 0 is
>   returned. On error, -1 is returned.

So your are going immediately out of the while loop. Of course this can be catched later when the first children terminates and a second one lets you process the `waitpid` again.

As you need to have a non-blocking call to wait I can suggest you not to manage termination directly but through `SIGCHLD` signal that will let you catch termination of any children and then appropriately call `waitpid` in the handler:

```
void handler(int signal) {
  while (waitpid(...)) { // find an adequate condition and paramters for your needs
}

...
struct sigaction act;
act.sa_flag = 0;
sigemptyset(&(act.sa_mask));
act.sa_handler = handler;
sigaction(SIGCHLD,&act,NULL);
... // now ready to receive SIGCHLD when at least a children changes its state
```

Comment: You can use signals to tell the parent that a client has been disconnected from child.

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Yunès could you give an example for the SIGCHLD usage.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to servicve multiple clients at once, and therefore your `waitpid` call is correct in that it does not block if no child has terminated.

However, the problem you then have is that you need to be able to process asynchronous child termination while waiting for new clients via `accept`. 
Assuming that you're dealing with a POSIXy system, merely having a `SIGCHLD` handler established and having the signal unmasked (via `sigprocmask`, though IIRC it is unmasked by default), should be enough to cause `accept` to fail with `EINTR` if a child terminates while you are waiting for a new client to connect - and you can then handle `EINTR` appropriately.

The reason for this is that a SIGCHLD signal will be automatically sent to the parent process when a child process terminates. In general, system calls such as `accept` will return an error of `EINTR` ("interrupted") if a signal is received while they are waiting.

However, there would still be a race condition, where a child terminates just *before* you call `accept` (i.e. in between where already have `waitpid` and `accept`). There are two main possibilities to overcome this:

1. Do all the child termination processing in your `SIGCHLD` handler, instead of the main loop. This may not be feasible, however, since there are significant limits to what you are allowed to do within a signal handler. You may not call `printf` for example (though you may use `write`).

   I do not suggest you go down this path, although it may seem simpler at first it is the least flexible option and may prove unworkable later.
2. Write to one end of a non-blocking pipe in your `SIGCHLD` signal handler. Within the main loop, instead of calling `accept` directly, use `poll` (or `select`) to look for readiness on both the socket and the read end of the pipe, and handle each appropriately.

   On Linux (and OpenBSD, I'm not sure about others) you can use `ppoll` ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ppoll)) to avoid the need to create a pipe (and in this case you should leave the signal masked, and have it unmasked during the poll operation; if `ppoll` fails with `EINTR`, you know that a signal was received, and you should call `waitpid`). You still need to set a signal handler for SIGCHLD, but it doesn't need to do anything.

   Another option on Linux is to use `signalfd` ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signalfd)) to avoid both the need to create a pipe and set up a signal handler (I think). You should mask the SIGCHLD signal (using `sigprocmask`) if you use this. When `poll` (or equivalent) indicates that the signalfd is active, read the signal data from it (which clears the signal) and then call `waitpid` to reap the child.

   On various BSD systems you can use `kqueue` ([OpenBSD man page](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man2/EV_SET.2)) instead of `poll` and watch for signals without needing to establish a signal handler.

   On other POSIX systems you may be able to use `pselect` ([documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pselect.html)) in a similar way to `ppoll` as described above.

   There is also the option of using a library such as [libevent](http://libevent.org/) to abstract away the OS-specifics.

The Glibc manual has [an example](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Waiting-for-I_002fO.html) of using `select`. Consult the manual pages for `poll`, `ppoll`, `pselect` for more information about those functions. There is an [online book](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/) on using Libevent.

Rough example for using `select`, borrowed from Glibc documentation (and modified):

```
/* Set up a pipe and set signal handler for SIGCHLD */

int pipefd[2]; /* must be a global variable */
pipe(pipefd); /* TODO check for error return */
fcntl(pipefd[1], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); /* set write end non-blocking */

/* signal handler */
void sigchld_handler(int signum)
{
    char a = 0; /* write anything, doesn't matter what */
    write(pipefd[1], &a, 1);
}

/* set up signal handler */
signal(SIGCHLD, sigchld_handler);
```

Where you currently have `accept`, you need to check status of the server socket and the read end of the pipe:

```
fd_set set, outset;
struct timeval timeout;

/* Initialize the file descriptor set. */
FD_ZERO (&set);
FD_SET (fdlisten[server], &set);
FD_SET (pipefds[0], &set);
FD_ZERO(&outset);

for (;;) {
    select (FD_SETSIZE, &set, NULL, &outset, NULL /* no timeout */));
    /* TODO check for error return.
       EINTR should just continue the loop. */

    if (FD_ISSET(fdlisten[server], &outset)) {
        /* now do accept() etc */
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(pipefds[0], &outset)) {
        /* now do waitpid(), and read a byte from the pipe */
    }
}
```

Using other mechanisms is generally simpler, so I leave those as an exercise :)